# CSV file in Python not giving the exact results

Tags: python, csv

I have created the following program and imported a CSV file containing words related to common phone problems. My problem is, that it will pick out "smashed" but it won't pick out "smashed," because of the comma.

So, my question is, how can I make it read the word without the comma and not giving me any errors or anything?

Any help will be appreciated :)

```
import csv

screen_list = {}

with open('keywords.csv') as csvfile:
readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile)
for row in readCSV:
    screen_list[row[0]] = row[1]

print("Welcome to the troubleshooting program. Here we will help you solve your problems which you are having with your phone. Let's get started: ")

what_issue = input("What is the issue with your phone?: ")
what_issue = what_issue.split(' ')

results = [(solution, screen_list[solution]) for solution in what_issue if   solution in screen_list]


if len(results) > 6:
    print('Please only insert a maximum of 6 problems at once. ')
else:
    for solution, problems in results:
        print('As you mentioned the word in your sentence which is: {}, the  possible outcome solution for your problem is: {}'.format(solution, problems))

exit_program = input("Type 0 and press ENTER to exit/switch off the program.")
```

Comment: Please show your own attempt to do this yourself and explain why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is when you `split` the `what_issue` string. The best solution is to use here a regular expression:

```
>>> import re 
>>> what_issue = "My screen is smashed, usb does not charge"
>>> what_issue.split(' ')
['My', 'screen', 'is', 'smashed,', 'usb', 'does', 'not', 'charge']

>>> print re.findall(r"[\w']+", what_issue ) 
['My', 'screen', 'is', 'smashed', 'usb', 'does', 'not', 'charge']
```

Answer (score 0):

You've encountered a topic in Computer Science called [tokenization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization_(lexical_analysis)).

It looks like you want to remove all non-alphabetical characters from the user input. An easy way to do that is to use Python's `re` library, which has support for regular expressions.

Here's an example of using `re` to do this:

```
import re
regex = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]')
regex.sub('', some_string)
```

First we create a regular expression that matches all characters that **aren't** letters. Then we use this regex to replace all the matching characters in `some_string` with an empty string, which deletes them from the string.

A quick-and-dirty method for doing the same thing would be to use the `isAlpha` method that belongs to all Python strings to filter out the unwanted characters.

```
some_string = ''.join([char for char in some_string if char.isAlpha()])
```

Here we make a list that only includes the alphabetical characters from `some_string`. Then we join it together to create a new string, which we assign to `some_string`.